# C++ Error in creating a linked list of an object that contains a linked list and a string

Tags: c++, linked-list

In the program below, I'm creating an object with one `string` and one `linkedlist<int>`.

I keep getting an unresolved issue due to the `obj` in `main()`. The error says:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   List::List(class List const &)"
>   (??0?$List@H@@QAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall
>   Data::Data(class Data const &)" (??0Data@@QAE@ABV0@@Z)

```
      main.cpp
            #include "List.h"
            #include <string>
            #include <iostream>
            #include <fstream>
            #include <utility> 
            using namespace std;

            template <class Object>
            void printList( const List<Object> & theList )  // SIMPLE PRINT FUNCTION
            {
                if( theList.isEmpty( ) )
                    cout << "Empty list" << endl;
                else
                {
                    ListItr<Object> itr = theList.first( );
                    for( ; !itr.isPastEnd( ); itr.advance( ) )
                        cout << itr.retrieve( ) << " ";
                }

                cout << endl;
            }

            class Data
            {
            public:

                Data(){
                    keyword = "";
                    List<int> pages;
                }

                void addNewData(string key, int article){

                    ListItr<int> pageitr = pages.zeroth();
                    keyword = key;
                    pages.insert(article, pageitr);

                }

                void addNewPage(int article){

                    ListItr<int> pageitr = pages.zeroth();
                    if(!pages.isExist(article))
                        pages.insert(article, pageitr);

                }


                bool operator==( const Data & rhs ){
                    if( this->keyword == rhs.keyword)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                bool  operator!=( const Data & rhs ){
                    if( this->keyword != rhs.keyword )
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            private:
                string keyword;
                List<int> pages;

            };



            int main( )
            {
                List<Data> trialdata;
                ListItr<Data> dataItr;
                ifstream input;  
                string s,k;
                int count = 0;

                string filename = "docdb.txt"; 
                input.open(filename.c_str());

                if (input.fail() )
                {   cout << "could not open file " << filename << endl;
                return 0;
                }

                /*while(input >> s){
                input >> k;
                addtoList(s, stoi(k), *trialdata);

                }*/


                return 0;
            }
```

The related header to this main is called `List.h`. It was taken from my course slides. I added one more function and tested it without the object I created. It works fine. Therefore, I'm thinking that there is problem in my object that it can't create a linked list inside a linked list.

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
using namespace std; 
#include <iostream>

template <class Object>
class List;     // Incomplete declaration.

template <class Object>
class ListItr;     // Incomplete declaration.

class  BadIterator {
public:
    BadIterator() {}
};


template <class Object>
class ListNode
{
    ListNode( const Object & theElement = Object( ),           
        ListNode * n = NULL )
        : element( theElement ), next( n ) { }

    Object   element;
    ListNode *next;

    friend class List<Object>;
    friend class ListItr<Object>;
};

template <class Object>
class ListItr
{
public:
    ListItr( ) : current( NULL ) { }
    bool isPastEnd( ) const
    { return current == NULL; }
    void advance( )
    { if( !isPastEnd( ) ) current = current->next; }
    const Object & retrieve( ) const
    { if( isPastEnd( ) ) throw BadIterator();
    return current->element; }

private:
    ListNode<Object> *current;    // Current position

    ListItr( ListNode<Object> *theNode )
        : current( theNode ) { }

    friend class List<Object>; // Grant access to constructor
};

template <class Object>
class List
{
private:
    ListNode<Object> *header;

public:
    List( ){
        header = new ListNode<Object>;
    }
    List( const List & rhs );
    ~List( )        {
        makeEmpty( );  // Get rid of all list nodes
        delete header;  // then get rid of the header
    }

    bool isEmpty( ) const{  // see if the header  point to NULL 
        return header->next == NULL;
    }
    void makeEmpty( ){
        while( !isEmpty( ) )
            remove( first( ).retrieve( ) );
    }
    ListItr<Object> zeroth( ) const{
        return ListItr<Object>( header );
    }
    ListItr<Object> first( ) const{
        return ListItr<Object>( header->next );
    }
    void insert( const Object & x, const ListItr<Object> & p ){
        if( p.current != NULL )
            p.current->next = new ListNode<Object>( x, p.current->next );
    }
    ListItr<Object> find( const Object & x ) const{
        ListNode<Object> *itr = header->next; // Initialize

        while( itr != NULL && itr->element != x )
            itr = itr->next;

        return ListItr<Object>( itr );
    }

        bool isExist( const Object & x ) const{
        ListNode<Object> *itr = header->next; // Initialize

        while( itr != NULL){
            if(itr->element == x)
                return true;
            itr = itr->next;
        }
        return false;
    }


    ListItr<Object> findPrevious( const Object & x ) const{
        ListNode<Object> *itr = header;

        while((itr->next != NULL) && itr->next->element != x )
            itr = itr->next;

        return ListItr<Object>( itr );
    }
    void remove( const Object & x ){
        ListItr<Object> p = findPrevious( x );

        if( p.current->next != NULL )
        {
            ListNode<Object> *oldNode = p.current->next;
            p.current->next = p.current->next->next;  // Bypass deleted node
            delete oldNode;
        }
    }

    const List & operator=( const List & rhs ){
        if( this != &rhs )
        {
            makeEmpty( );

            ListItr<Object> ritr = rhs.first( );
            ListItr<Object> itr = zeroth( );
            for( ; !ritr.isPastEnd( ); ritr.advance( ), itr.advance( ) )
                insert( ritr.retrieve( ), itr );
        }
        return *this;
    }

};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Your header declares a copy-constructor for the `List` template:

```
template<class Object>
class List
{
    // ...
    List( const List & rhs );
```

However, this copy constructor is not defined anywhere.

Therefore, your compiler, when compiling this translation unit, will assume that the template instance will be defined in another translation unit and emits external symbol reference. And since the copy constructor is not defined anywhere, your program fails to link.

The error your compiler reports is a classical undefined symbol error, due to a missing template method instantiation.

You need to implement and define the copy constructor for this template, [in your header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 1):

You *declared* a copy constructor for `List`, but you did not *implement* it:

```
template <class Object>
class List
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    List( const List & rhs ); // <-- DECLARATION ONLY!
    ...
};
```

The linker is complaining that it can't find an implementation for `List(const List &)` (which is called by the compiler-generated copy constructor for `Data` when copying the `pages` member <sup>1</sup>).

It is common practice to implement a copy assignment operator using the copy constructor, eg:

```
template <class Object>
class List
{
    ...    
public:
    ...

    List( const List & src ){
        header = new ListNode<Object>;
        ListItr<Object> sitr = src.first( );
        ListItr<Object> itr = zeroth( );
        for( ; !sitr.isPastEnd( ); sitr.advance( ), itr.advance( ) )
            insert( sitr.retrieve( ), itr );
        }
    }

    ...

    List& operator=( const List & rhs ){
        if( this != &rhs )
        {
            List<Object> temp(rhs);
            std::swap(temp.header, header);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ...
};
```

<sup>1: BTW, your `Data()` default constructor is not needed at all.  `std::string` has its own default constructor, so your initialization of the `Data::keyword` member is redundant, and the constructor is declaring an unused *local* `List` variable named `pages` that shadows the `Data:::pages` member.  Since `List` also has a default constructor, there is no need to try to initialize the `Data::pages` member explicitly.</sup>